# python combine by key or value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like below

```
ID |Identifier1 | Identifier2 
---------------------------------
1  |      a     | c         
2  |      b     | f         
3  |      a     | g         
4  |      c     | h        
5  |      b     | j         
6  |      d     | f         
7  |      e     | k  
8  |      i     |          
9  |      l     | h
```

The desired output is below

```
Identifier | Gr_ID    |    Gr.Members                 
---------------------------------------------------
a          |   1      |   (a,c,g,h,l)  
b          |   2      |   (b,d,f,j)       
c          |   1      |   (a,c,g,h,l)  
d          |   2      |   (b,d,f,j)       
e          |   3      |   (e,k)                 
f          |   2      |   (b,d,f,j)       
g          |   1      |   (a,c,g,h,l)  
h          |   1      |   (a,c,g,h,l)  
j          |   2      |   (b,d,f,j)       
k          |   3      |   (e,k)                 
l          |   1      |   (a,c,g,h,l)  
i          |   4      |   (i)
```

How can I get the desired output? Looked at the dictionary methods and not finding any where we can group by key or value.

Comment: What your desired output is based on? Can you explain a little bit more on how you get Gr. Members?

Comment: The group members are all the linkages on a graph. So "a" is connected to itself, "c", "g", "h" and "l" in the original table. In the desired output it shows as such in the Gr. Members column

Comment: I think this is a graph problem of finding connected nodes along edges in a graph network.  Let's look at using networkx library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When see this type of "path" problems I think of "graphs". Networkx is a python library that handles graph networks. Let's use the networkx:

```
#Import libraries
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

#Read in data into a pandas dataframe    
txt = StringIO("""ID|Identifier1|Identifier2
1|a|c
2|b|f
3|a|g
4|c|h
5|b|j
6|d|f
7|e|k
8|i|    
9|l|h""")   

df = pd.read_csv(txt,sep='|')

#Create Graph network using networkx

G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df,source='Identifier1',target='Identifier2')

#Create output dataframe using graph `nodes` and `node_connected_component`
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Identifier':sorted(G.nodes())})\
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.Identifier,
               sorted(list(nx.node_connected_component(G,x.Identifier)))]), axis=1)
df1.columns = ['Identifier','Gr.Members']

#Use pd.factorize to create unique ids for each group of connected components
df1['Gr_ID'] = pd.factorize(df1['Gr.Members'].apply(tuple))[0] + 1

df1
```

Output:

```
   Identifier       Gr.Members  Gr_ID
0                    [    , i]      1
1           a  [a, c, g, h, l]      2
2           b     [b, d, f, j]      3
3           c  [a, c, g, h, l]      2
4           d     [b, d, f, j]      3
5           e           [e, k]      4
6           f     [b, d, f, j]      3
7           g  [a, c, g, h, l]      2
8           h  [a, c, g, h, l]      2
9           i        [    , i]      1
10          j     [b, d, f, j]      3
11          k           [e, k]      4
12          l  [a, c, g, h, l]      2
```